# How to post an array though RestRequest?

Tags: c#, rest

I have two distinct programs. One is a manager and another is a service. Inside the manager, I get *schoolIds* and *trigger* which I would like to pass to the Service using RestRequest. When I execute the below code, I get the *trigger* in the service but ***schoolIds*** array comes as empty.

I am fairly new to C#, any help will be great !!

**Manager**

```
var schoolIds = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

var request = new RestRequest("/api/School", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("schoolIds", schoolIds);
request.AddParameter("trigger", trigger);

var response = schoolRestClient.Execute(request);
```

**Service**

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LookUpSchoolsPost(string[] schools, string trigger)
{
    schoolsService.SchoolsLookup(schools, trigger);
    return Ok();
}
```

Class SchoolsService:

```
public void SchoolsLookup(string[] schools, string trigger)
{
    logger.Info($"Info: schoolIds= {schools}, trigger={trigger}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I was able to make work for the kind of situation you are in. I would recommend using a JsonObject instead of two separate string/string[] to your POST call for clean and complete call.

This should work for you,

```
var request = new RestRequest("/api/School/?trigger=triggerstring", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("schoolIds", "[\"A\", \"B\"]", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

**Suggestion**

Use a class for your input object and then use AddJsonBody (instead of addParameters) since thats whats recommended by [RestSharp documentation](http://restsharp.org/usage/parameters.html#request-body).

```
public class LookupRequest {
    [JsonProperty("schoolIds")]
    public List<string> SchoolIds {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("trigger")]
    public string Trigger {get;set;}
}

// and in your main class

var lookupRequest = new LookupRequest() 
{
    SchoolIds = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" }
    trigger = "TriggerEvent"
};

var request = new RestRequest("/api/School", Method.POST);
request.AddJsonBody(lookupRequest);

var response = schoolRestClient.Execute(request);
```

and your endpoint would look like,

```
public ActionResult LookUpSchoolsPost(LookupRequest request)
{
    // Do away with request.SchoolIds and request.Trigger
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I did something similar to what you suggested after looking around Internet. `var stringOfschoolIds = String.Join(",", new List<string>(schoolIds).ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());`